# custom django-admin commands - method not found

Tags: django, python-3.x

While running a django-admin command - it can't find a local method.

**update.py**

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = 'Help Test'
    def handle(self, **options):
        test1 = 'hello'
        doThis()

    def doThis():
        test2 = 'hello'
```

running the command `python3 manage.py update` produces the error:

```
File "/opt/dir/app/management/commands/updatefm.py", line 25, in handle
        doThis()
    NameError: name 'doThis' is not defined
```

I can't quite see a reason for this in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/#methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you're missing about how Python handles classes and objects.

`Command.handle` is calling a method, `doThis`, from the same class so you should use `self`:

```
def handle(self, **options):
    test1 = 'hello'
    self.doThis()
```

And then you should change the signature of `doThis` so Python can use it as a method of the class `Command`:

```
def doThis(self):
    test2 = 'hello'
```